# Update boolean property only if current value is false

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a document for video progress. There's a `isFinished` field wherein the value is false if the user hasn't finished watching the video yet. Once the user finishes watching it, it should be updated to true.

I'm only checking the current time of the video against the actual length of the video to determine the `isFinished` to pass to the update method. Thing is, if a user has already finished watching a video, decides to watch it again, and doesn't finish it, the document shouldn't update the value of `isFinished to false`.

How do I then update it only if the current value of the property is false?

```
MyCollection.upsert({
    userId: this.userId,
    videoId: videoId
}, {
    $set: {
        userId: this.userId,
        videoId: videoId,
        videoStartTime: videoStartTime,
        isFinished: isFinished //only change this if current value is not false
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to consider the `isFinished` field value when selecting your documents.

Comment: @user3100115 but what if I want to update other properties like `videoStartTime` and just skip the `isFinished`?

Comment: You can't do that. It's simply not possible. You will need to first retrieve the `isFinished` field value then use an `if/else` statement depending on the value.

Answer (score 1):

This command should work correctly.

```
db.collectionname.update({isFinished:false},{$set:{isFinished:true}})
```

Comment: but what if I want to update other properties like `videoStartTime` and just skip the `isFinished`?